# Add an index to improve performance of this query?

Tags: firebird, indexing

Using: Firebird 2.52

For performance of SELECT for the following query, do I require indexes on additional fields in my table:

Desired query:

```
select inventory_id, max(batch_no) from invty_batch
where inventory_id = :I
group by inventory_id
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE INVTY_BATCH (
  ROW_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  INVENTORY_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  BATCH_NO VARCHAR(8) NOT NULL,
  INVTYRCPT_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
  UNITPRICE NUMERIC(12, 2) DEFAULT 0.0 NOT NULL);


ALTER TABLE INVTY_BATCH ADD PRIMARY KEY (ROW_ID);


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IXINVTYIDBATCHNO ON INVTY_BATCH(INVENTORY_ID,BATCH_NO);
```

Will creating indexes on inventory_id and batch_no columns benefit performance for the given query?

Comment: Firebird indexes are directional, you might benefit from a descending index on `INVTY_BATCH(INVENTORY_ID,BATCH_NO)` in this case; not sure though.

Comment: @ Mark Roteveel if @Steve F is grouping by INVENTORY_ID shouldn't it be there an index on just that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to create an index for the field "batch_no", because the query is doing a search in this field.
PS : Use a desc index, because the search is for the max value

Comment: Thanks for replying. 
1. Should I create 2 indexes for Batch_No? One ASC, and one DESC?
2. Do I also need to create an index on Inventory_ID?

Comment: A (descending) compound index as suggested in my comment is probably better.

Comment: 1 - Use two indices, one for the field Inventory_ID, and another for Batch_No DESC will be two indices because they are different scans